# Проверка подключена ли external usb-камера к девайсу

Tags: android, камера, web-camera

Подскажите, есть ли возможность выполнять проверку подключена ли внешняя (external) usb - камера к устройству ( использую camera2 API).

класс `CameraMetadata` имеет поле

```
public static final int LENS_FACING_EXTERNAL = 2;
```

Но я не нашел  с чем сравнить это поле для того чтобы выполнить данную проверку.

Если использовать такой способ :

```
getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_EXTERNAL)
```

то я , так понимаю, происходит проверка доступно ли использование внешней камеры на устройстве, а вовсе не состояние ее подключения в данный момент. Буду признателен за помощь.

Answer (score 1):

Существует UsbManager, который даст вам нужную информация. Действия.

1.Регистрируем BroadCastReceiver c нужным action (подключение/отключение)

2.В onReceiver из intent вынимаем необходимую инфу устройства (EXTRA_DEVICE)

3.Делаем проверку, что это именно, то устройство, которое необходимо.

4.Любая логика. (Сообщаем пользователю, "Камера - подключена")

Comment: мне непонятно насчет третьего пункта.Т.е. как проверить что это подключенное устройство - камера.Так же возможен вариант : допустим,устройство имеет фронтальную и тыльную камеры, а еще подключается usb-camera. При переключении между камерами необходимо четко знать, какая именно камера в данный момент работает. как это сделать? С фронтальной/тыльной  - все просто.а если  есть еще usb -камера?